# Angularjs $window.open not working properly IOS and Android

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-mobile, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I have a question regarding $window.open in angularjs. 
I am having the following angularjs function

$scope.contentPopup = function() {

```
        var tndWindow  = $window.open('/content', '', '_blank');
        tndWindow.document.write($scope.content);
    };
```

It works well good on laptop browsers. I can give the dimentions to the window and it displays well on browsers.
But it just doesn't seem to work on mobile devices(both ios and andriod) with the dimensions given to window. It overlaps the whole screen which I do not want. Can anybody suggest how to make this new window behave same in all browsers and mobile devices.

Comment: Can you inject the $window in your controller or anywhere?

Comment: Other than simple use window instead of $window

Comment: I have already injected $window in my controller and using it.. i do not prefer to use javascript window when we have angularjs $window...

Comment: please change _blank to _system.
var tndWindow  = $window.open('/content', '', '_system');

Comment: But it doesnt seem to work well ..i expect it to atleast display in proper dimension..if i give dimension then how will it map to a mobile device dimension